# Template binding Magento2.4.5 not working in checkout

Tags: magento2.4.5

Since we have upgraded to magento 2.4.5 the popup URl is not showing mij carrier_custom template.

if I put the data binding as a normaly shown object it works correct.
but if the popup is clicked I recieve below message in the console

[image]

if we use the plugin in older version it runs fine

the code I have used in de JS file is:

```
   bindFeather: function () {
        $.featherlight.defaults.root = '#featherroot';
        $.featherlight.defaults.beforeOpen = function (element) {

            if (typeof element != 'undefined') {

                var templateName = element.currentTarget.dataset.featherlight.substr(1);
                var templatePlaceholder = '<div data-bind="template: {name:\'dm-delivery-methods-content\'}"></div>';



                $('#featherroot').find('.featherlight-content').html(templatePlaceholder).first().each(function () {

                    var bindingContext = ko.contextFor($(this).get());

                    $(this).each(function () {
                        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, this);
                    });
                });


                return {controlsDescendantBindings: true};
            }
        };
    },
```

the Carrier_custom.html starts with :

```
<div class="lightbox dm-lightbox" id="dm-delivery-methods"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="dm-delivery-methods-content">

    <h2 data-bind="i18n: getPopupTitle()"></h2>

    <div class="dm-address">

        <div class="dm-methods-container">

            <div class="dm-dates">

                <!-- ko foreach: { data: availableDates, as: 'date'} -->

                <div class="dm-delivery-date" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.selectDate(date.standard) }, css: { selected: $parent.selectedDate() == date.standard }">
                    <span data-bind="text: date.formatted"></span>
                    <div class="dm-methods-lowestprice" data-bind="css: { free: date.fromPrice === '0,00' }">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'From: '"></span>
                        <span data-bind="text: '&#8364' + date.fromPrice"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the Phtml is also correct stup and the XML file refers to the correct template.

sample checkout page:

[image]
I have searched the internet but no matching case found.
but somehow is does not work can somebody please help

thanks in advance

kind regards
Ruud

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPopupTitle` function didn't define. If you have declared that function, but it does not work post the full file content of this function here, and I'll help.

Comment: Hi, your correct, the getpopup tilte is a value of the array which contains the data what should be loaded if the popup is clicked.

Comment: the array data is the same as the data in the picture which has the popup written behind it. so the data is called correct, but only if the URL is used it does not work. in version 2.4.4 it workes correct.  which function you want to see complete. thanks in advance

Comment: It is `getPopupTitle` function.

Comment: Hi Tu Van,   te getpopup title is not the problem, this is a fucntion which is called when the array with data should be loaded in de popup. but this is not working at the moment,

Comment: Could you edit your question to add file content of all related files (It will be JS, html, and layout files) that use for the popup feature? So I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

no this is not correct, the array which contains for instance getPopupTitle fucntions is not loaded at all,

looks like the 2 rows somehow are not working anymore

```
 $.featherlight.defaults.root = '#featherroot';
        $.featherlight.defaults.beforeOpen = function (element) {
```

somehow after 2.4.3 version of MAgento2 it does not work anymore in version 2.4.3 the popup works perfect, with the same code.

somewhere in this version there is something changed which I could not find yet in de MAgento docs.

But thanks for the help

kind regards
Ruud